# How to color a bar when several conditions are met?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Hi I am trying to code an indicator that colors the current bar if 10 to 12 candles ago we had a Swing High (SH) and current RSI is oversold. Also if 10 to 12 bars ago we had a Swing Low (SL) and current RSI is overbought.

```
SH = open[5] < close[5] and open[4] < close[4] and open[3] < close[3] and open[2] > close[2] and open[1] > close[1] and open[0] > close[0]

SL = open[5] > close[5] and open[4] > close[4] and open[3] > close[3] and open[2] < close[2] and open[1] < close[1] and open[0] < close[0]
```

I have no idea to this problem

Comment: What are `SH` and `SL`? Swing high and low?

Comment: SH = open[5] < close[5] and open[4] < close[4] and open[3] < close[3] and open[2] > close[2] and open[1] > close[1] and open[0] > close[0]

Comment: SL = open[5] > close[5] and open[4] > close[4] and open[3] > close[3] and open[2] < close[2] and open[1] < close[1] and open[0] < close[0]

Comment: this is how they would look in the present

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator("swing/rsi", overlay = true)

swing_start_lb = input.int(10, title = "Start of Swing lookback")
swing_end_lb = input.int(12, title ="End of Swing lookback" )

ob = input.float(80, title = "RSI OB")
os = input.float(20, title = "RSI OS")

SH = open[5] < close[5] and open[4] < close[4] and open[3] < close[3] and open[2] > close[2] and open[1] > close[1] and open[0] > close[0]
SL = open[5] > close[5] and open[4] > close[4] and open[3] > close[3] and open[2] < close[2] and open[1] < close[1] and open[0] < close[0]
plotshape(SH, title = "Swing High", style = shape.triangledown, location = location.abovebar, color = color.red)
plotshape(SL, title = "Swing Low", style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, color = color.green)

r = ta.rsi(close, 14)
bgcolor(r >= ob ? color.new(color.red, 80) : r <= os ? color.new(color.green, 80) : #00000000)

bool SH_RSIOS_cond = false
bool SL_RSIOB_cond = false

for i = swing_start_lb to swing_end_lb
    if SH[i] and r <= os
        SH_RSIOS_cond := true
    if SL[i] and r >= ob
        SL_RSIOB_cond := true 

barcolor(SH_RSIOS_cond ? color.aqua : na)
barcolor(SL_RSIOB_cond ? color.fuchsia : na)
```